# How to enable port 5000 on AWS ubuntu

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask, ubuntu-14.04

I have a flask app running on AWS Ubuntu server on port 5000 (flask runs default on port 5000). But when I try to access the server on that port, it never connects.

I added a security group on AWS console as `Custom TCP` on port `5000` for any ip address `0.0.0.0/0`, but still I cannot access it.

Do I have to restart the server? Or am I missing anything?

Let me know any additional information to provide.

Comment: Can you post the output of `netstat -an | grep :5000`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In addition to allowing access to port 5000 via the Security Group, you also need to ensure that your app is listening on an IP which can accept TCP connections from outside. To listen on all IPs, in your app, use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug = False)
```

Instead of:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', debug = False)
```

To see what address your application is listening on, you can run this command:

```
netstat -an | grep :5000
```

After making these changes, you will want to restart your Flask application.

I'm assuming you're just using this for development and testing, since you're keeping it on port `5000`, but, when you're ready to deploy your application into production, you need to put it behind a real webserver. I would recommend using [nginx](http://nginx.org) with [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). [Here is a guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) to configuring Flask + nginx + uWSGI, and here is the [official documentation from Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/uwsgi/) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks @Will I would like to do the similar thing you mentioned by using nginx and uWSGI. The document would help me.

Comment: your answer was just perfect. Thanks again

Comment: No problem at all, I'm glad I could help you out :)

Comment: Thanks Will, got it working.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, I had to search for 1 hour to find this

Answer (score 14):

In addition to @Will's answer, its possible that whichever Ubuntu AMI you're using came with restrictive iptables rules by default.
Use:

```
sudo iptables -L
```

to list any current rules that exist.
Use:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT
```

to open the port if necessary.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of that, thanks :)

Comment: This helped me on my Amazon Linux AMI with ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"