# Docker on Amazon Cloud

Tags: python, docker, flask, amazon-ec2

I have an *Amazon Cloud ec2* instance running a Dockerized *flask* application. I can connect to the instance via *ssh*, but when deploying and trying to connect to the public DNS via my browser, I'm unable to access the deployed flask application. The web page will always simply time out. How do I view my running application? Thank you so much in advance!

Unfortunately, the suggestions made in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864499/how-to-enable-port-5000-on-aws-ubuntu didn't help. I'm having issues running it independently of Docker on AWS. I've installed Apache and can see the default page, but still haven't been able to run the flask application. Is my instance not configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the host port through which you are accessing the container is open in security group.

Also try to curl the application internally on the ec2-instance.If it is working internally they you need to check security groups in AWS.